# Centre a label within my user control that is positioned within a canvas WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, label, alignment

Attempting to centre my label in my User Control to my 'signal' I have drawn within my canvas.

[image]

This is what my signals currently look like, with their names below the signal. As you can see, due to the variation in name length, some are off centred.

My user control XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Name="LeftUserControl"
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.84,0.5">

    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Width="10" Height="10">
        <Canvas Height="150" Width="150">
                <Label Content="{Binding SignalName, ElementName=LeftUserControl}" Foreground="Black" Canvas.Top="108" FontSize="15" Canvas.Left="85"></Label>
                <Line X1="130" X2="130" Y1="105" Y2="84" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" ></Line>
                <Line X1="130" X2="100" Y1="105" Y2="105" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5"></Line>
                <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="25" Height="25" Canvas.Left="85" Canvas.Top="92"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>


</UserControl>
```

My main window where I'm using my user control:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SignalLeftViewModel}">
                            <Canvas>
                                <userControls:SignalLeftControl SignalName="{Binding Name}" Canvas.Top="{Binding SignalCoords.Y, Converter={StaticResource ScaleYCoordConverter},ConverterParameter=leftSignal}" Canvas.Left="{Binding SignalCoords.X, Converter={StaticResource ScaleXCoordConverter}, ConverterParameter=leftSignal}">
                                    <userControls:SignalLeftControl.RenderTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>
                                    </userControls:SignalLeftControl.RenderTransform>
                                </userControls:SignalLeftControl>

                            </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

I'm wondering what the easiest way is to centre my label within my user control, so that all the names are aligned properly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just change the way your UserControl is designed. use Grid at the top of the UC and then split it using 2 columns, first column will have your label ? (what happened to TextBlock?) and the other will have your canvas and drawing. Your RenderTransform is slightly off the centre.

Comment: When I thought about using a grid I assumed I'd have to do all the drawings within the grid, I didn't think about using a Canvas within the grid, I think that might work, cheers. As for the render transform, it's meant to be slightly off centre due to the way I've had to design everything, don't worry. The signals are all in their correct positions. @XAMlMAX